# pyvisa use in Matlab for network-connected instruments

Tags: python, matlab, pyvisa

I am trying to use the 'pyvisa' library from within Matlab to communicate with VISA-supported instruments on the local network. Some of these instruments are attached through a GPIB-Ethernet bridge, while others are directly connected through TCPIP.

To load the 'pyvisa' library in Matlab, I use

```
pyvisa = py.importlib.import_module('pyvisa');
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager();
```

From here, one can open instruments by either specifying the fully-qualified VISA identifier or the alias defined, for example, in Keysight Connection Expert.

```
handle = rm.open_resource('GPIB_AliasName');
handle2 = rm.open_resource('TCPIP0::K-12345B-12345::5025::SOCKET');
```

When it comes to communicating with the instrument, there appears to a difference between those connected through GPIB (using the network bridge) and those via TCPIP, such as the 'handle2' instrument above.

As an example, issuing a command such as

```
handle.query('*IDN?')
```

results in the return of the instrument identifier (as a Python string, py.str), while the following

```
handle2.query('*IDN?')
```

times out.

One of the properties of the VISA object (as created using pyvisa) in Matlab is the 'read_termination' and 'write_termination'. Setting the former to '\n' results in parts of the queried identifier to be returned, but broken up into odd chunks, such as

```
>> handle2.query('*IDN?')

ans = 

  Python str with no properties.

    Agilen
```

which should have read 'Agilent Technologies,33522B,MYxxxxx,3.05-1.19-2.00-52-00', and is being read back as such doing the same from a Python interpreter. I played with the termination string, using both '\n', '\r', and '\r\n', as well as these being passed by first converting them to Python strings via py.str('\n'), etc. Nothing works.

Ideas on what to try next would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

p.s.: Calling a Python function from within Matlab that sets the read termination once for each instrument handle resolves the issue described above, which points towards a translation problem of the '\n' string passed from Matlab to the Python pyvisa object.

Comment: So does communication with all the instruments work OK from a Python prompt? If so you could try writing a Python function that does the send and receive, and calling that function from MATLAB?

Comment: @nekomatic The answer to both of these questions is 'yes'. Going through a Python function that handles the device interface would have been my next step, but since some of the communication involves transferring a large amount of data, I was trying to keep it as simple as possible initially. Indeed, I will now try to at least implement simple communication through external function calls. Thanks.

Comment: I finally found the solution. Instead of `handle.read_termination = '\n'` one needs to use `handle.read_termination = newline` or `handle.read_termination = sprintf('\n')`.

Comment: Good to hear! You can write this up as an answer to your own question if you like.